# Parsing value into php function

Tags: php, html, rest

I'm trying to pass an number value into function in a for loop.

The problem is that the value is not being parsed so the function runs , but does not take the number of each for loop into account and therefor the result of the function is wrong.

```
$stars = $hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating'];
for($x=0;$x<$sizeOfPageSearch;$x++)
    echo "<li><a class='booking-item' href=\"/hotels/hotelPage.php?go&customerSessionId=$customerSessionId&hotelId=" . $hotelSummary[$x]['hotelId'] . "&arrival=" . strval($_GET['arrival']) . "&departure=" . strval($_GET['departure']) . "&exHotelId=" . $hotelSummary[$x]['RoomRateDetailsList']['RoomRateDetails']['expediaPropertyId'] . " \"><div class='row'><div class='col-md-3'><div class='booking-item-img-wrap'>" . "<img style='width:200px; height:150px;' src='" . $imagehost . $newImgUrl = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $hotelSummary[$x]['thumbNailUrl']) . "'/>" . "<div class='booking-item-img-num'><i class='fa fa-picture-o'></i>12</div></div></div>" . "<div class='col-md-6'><div class='booking-item-rating'><ul class='icon-group booking-item-rating-stars'><li>" . stars($stars) . "</li></ul>" . "<span class='booking-item-rating-number'><b>" .  $hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating'] . "</b> of 5</span><small>( " . $hotelSummary[$x]['tripAdvisorReviewCount'] . " reviews )</small></div>" . "<h5 class='booking-item-title'>" . $hotelSummary[$x]['name'] . "</h5>" . "<p class='booking-item-address'><i class='fa fa-map-marker'></i> " . $hotelSummary[$x]['locationDescription'] . "</p><small class='booking-item-last-booked'>Latest booking: 39 minutes ago</small></div><div class='col-md-3'><span class='booking-item-price-from'>from</span><span class='booking-item-price'>" . ceil($hotelSummary[$x]['RoomRateDetailsList']['RoomRateDetails']['RateInfos']['RateInfo']['ChargeableRateInfo']['@total']) . "</span><span>kr/totalt</span><span class='btn btn-primary'>Book Now</span></div></div></a></li>"; 

    if(empty($sizeOfPageSearch)) {
        echo "No results were found </br>";
    }
}
function stars($stars){
    $stars = $hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating'];
    for($i=1;$i<=$stars;$i++) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
    }
    if (strpos($stars,'.')) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-empty'></i>";
        $i++;
    }
    while ($i<=5) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I'm setting sizeOfPageSearch in the top in a for each loop. Also surrounding the for loop.

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
$hotelSummary = $value['HotelList']['HotelSummary'];
$sizeOfSearch = $value['HotelList']['@activePropertyCount'];
$sizeOfPageSearch = $value['HotelList']['@size'];
```

For every loop `$stars` should hold an integer gained from a `REST` response. That integer is hold here: `$hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating']` <- I know this have the number and it works as I can var_dump the integer for every loop. But I can't seem to parse that integer for every loop into the function `stars()`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call you stars() function, you *are* passing in the value from `$hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating']` into the function.  You shouldn't be reassigning `$stars` within the function, because you just passed the value in!  `$hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating']` won't exist within the scope of your function anyway so it's likely setting the value to `null`.

So you define your function and the pass in the value to run the function:

```
function stars($stars){

    // Line not required
    //$stars = $hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating'];

    for($i=1;$i<=$stars;$i++) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star'></i>";
    }
    if (strpos($stars,'.')) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-half-empty'></i>";
        $i++;
    }
    while ($i<=5) {
        echo "<i class='fa fa-star-o'></i>";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I call the stars function in the echo right under the for loop starting for($x=0;$x<$sizeOfPageSearch;$x++)
    echo .... in here stars($stars); is called.

Comment: also the value in here : $hotelSummary[$x]['hotelRating']; is different for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should show more of the script and specifically the place you are calling stars from.

Also,

> **What am I doing wrong here?**

In general:

1) You are not filtering the $_GET variable. You should sanitize the value before echoing it.

2) You are using an index for a loop ($x) as a global variable, so if you are calling stars function after the first loop, $x would be out of array range, in my honest opinion, the index variable for a loop **should not** be global, at least when not properly maintaining it..

3) You are overwriting your parameter $stars in the function stars function, why do that? Either remove the parameter definition or use it.

4) You can use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) to get the integer value